# grep: how to show only one word after found one?

Tags: grep, xinput

I would like to write a script to disable keyboard. I write `xinput disable 13` as built-in keyboard's id = 13.
But what if the 'id' changes somehow? Then it won't work anymore. That's why I have to write better script, the one that uses grep.

For now, I got this

```
xinput list|grep AT|grep id=
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I added `cut -f 2` to my command, so it displays this > id=13
So, for now, I got 'id=13', but I need only 13, without id=, so I could assign that value to some variable, to pass it to `xinput disable $variable`

Can someone help me to complete my script?

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to specify a numeric index, the following commands suffices:

```
xinput --disable 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
```

Have a look at the xinput manual page for more recipes.

---

If you want to parse the ID using grep, you could use the following:

```
$ xinput list | grep -Po 'AT.*id=\K[0-9]+'
13
```

For more details about `\K`, see [Can grep output only specified groupings that match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13466/8250).

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

`xinput list|grep AT|grep id=|cut -f 2|cut -f 2 -d =`

`cut` command has an option to specify the delimiter.

`xinput list|grep AT|grep id=|cut -f 2`

This gives you `id=13`, so pass it to another cut command specifying the delimiter as =

**Sample**

```
~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Premium USB Optical Mouse            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
~$ xinput list|grep AT|grep id=|cut -f 2|cut -f 2 -d =
14
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want a substring?

```
string=$(xinput | grep HID | cut -f 2);
echo ${string:3}
```

This does not work in shell only in bash

```
chad@M4A79XTD-EVO:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:0033                             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
chad@M4A79XTD-EVO:~$ string=$(xinput | grep HID | cut -f 2);echo ${string:3}
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can use grep for this, I think you would be better off with sed here:

```
xinput list | sed -nr 's/.*AT.*keyboard.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is old it lead me to my solution which is much simpler than previous answers. Checking the man pages as Lekensteyn suggested and this is what I found.

```
# Keyboard, TouchPad, Mouse, etc...
DvcName=`xinput list --name-only | grep "QueryYourDevice"`
DvcId=`xinput list --id-only "$DvcName"`       # Save Device Id.....
```

Now you have both the device name and id stored and can use easily throughout the script.